# Why is Extension Manager missing in VS2015 Community?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I noticed there isn't "Extension manager" in "Tools" menu in my VS2015 community anymore! What may have caused that?

I uninstalled it, then re-install VS2015 professional and found it again right after the first launch.  The next launch it disappeared again (with the other extensions as well) !

This is what I've done so far:

1- Uninstall again.

2- Delete "extensions" folder from "C:\user(USERNAME)\local\microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0"

3- Reinstall (pro version).

4- Same problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone encountering this issue, after many useless uninstallings:
Run (from start menu) "Visual Studio professional" not "Visual Studio Blend"... that's all :)